# Trying to overwrite a const char * is a bad access

Tags: c

I wrote a simple in-place string reversal function, which works on leetcode (interview practice), but gives a surprising bad-access error on my own system.  It's such a simple function and everything else the debugger tells me seems like it should be A-OK.  Why am I getting the bad access?

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char* reverseString(char* s) {
  char *t,*r,tmp;
  t=r=s;
  while(*(s++));
  s-=2;
  while(t<s){
    tmp=*t;
    *t=*s; //<--- this is where I have a bad access(?)
    *s=tmp;
    s--;
    t++;
  }
  return r;
}

int main(){
  char *s="12345";
  reverseString(s);
  return 0;
}
```

Bear with me, the debugger info is super simple.

```
╰─$ lldb ./a.out
lldb ./a.out
(lldb) target create "./a.out"
Current executable set to './a.out' (x86_64).
(lldb) r
r
Process 38750 launched: './a.out' (x86_64)
Process 38750 stopped
* thread #1: tid = 0xa0c378, 0x0000000100000f23 a.out`reverseString(s="5") + 99 at reverse-string.c:12, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x100000f91)
    frame #0: 0x0000000100000f23 a.out`reverseString(s="5") + 99 at reverse-string.c:12
   9      s-=2;
   10     while(t<s){
   11       tmp=*t;
-> 12       *t=*s;
   13       *s=tmp;
   14       s--;
   15       t++;
(lldb) frame variable
frame variable
(char *) s = 0x0000000100000f95 "5"
(char *) t = 0x0000000100000f91 "12345"
(char *) r = 0x0000000100000f91 "12345"
(char) tmp = '1'
(lldb) call *s
call *s
(char) $0 = '5'
(lldb) call *t
call *t
(char) $1 = '1'
(lldb) call *t=*s
call *t=*s
(char) $2 = '5'
(lldb)
```

Notice that I can even call `*t=*s;` in lldb and get the expected result.  What gives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modifying a string constant is undefined behavior. Even when you cast it to `char *` that doesn't make it okay.

Try making a non-const copy on the stack or heap first.

Comment: I see.  So the function is fine, but I shouldn't be passing it a string constant.  That explains why leetcode, which makes the test cases properly, doesn't throw the error.  This had me worried, thinking if I can't do this then...

Answer (score 2):

in

```
int main(){
  char *s="12345";
```

s is a `const char *`. You assign it to a `char *` (which should give a warning), but that doesn't mean you can now change it. It is still a `const`. In older OS, this is not protected, meaning you can modify data storage. This is hackers-101 way to get access to something - write machine code over a (supposedly) const string, and get it executed later, and - bingo!

Newer OS protect this by marking memory pages with const data as such (and also marking them as non-executable - 'Data execution Protection' in windows).